# Any way to force SSMS to recognize some basic HTML code or auto replace it?

Tags: ssms

I do a lot of copy/pasting between xml files in java and sql in SSMS. SSMS needs "less than" to be the < symbol but html needs it to be `&lt;`. It isn't a big issue because ctrl+f replace all has been doing the job for some time now, but is there a way to make SSMS notice `&lt;` and act correctly? Or automatically replace it when I paste in code?

Notes:

SSMS 2017

Running with APEXSQL Complete plug in